# How can I create a database Firebase where relationships are one to many?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, web

I need to create a common database in Firebase for web and IOS app. How can I create relationships like one to many? I need to have authentication of users, which can add one or many publications. So one user can have many publications. Futhermore, I need to have chat in app. I am really stuck with this and can not find answer how I need to structure my database. Please help me.

Comment: It will help others to help you if you include your attempt and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Firebase has two databases: Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore. To ensure that you get answers that are most immediately useful to you, please tag with the database you're looking to use: `firebase-realtime-database` or `google-cloud-firestore`.

Answer (score 1):

For one to many relationships you can use [Subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections). So you have could User-Collection with all the User-Documents in it. Every User-Document will then have a Publications-Collection attached to it, where all the Publication-Documents are saved.

For the chat, you should provide more information on where you are stuck. There are many resources out there, which discuss the different approaches to implementing a chat in Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

**First create a child USERS:**

```
“users”: {
 “uid-1234”: {
    “name”: “Jon Doe”
}
```

}

**Then you create a child for your PUBLICATIONS:**

```
“publications” : {
    “uid-0987”: {
        “post”: “Hello world!!!”
        “posted_by”: “uid-1234”
    }
}
```

**And then for your CHAT:**

```
 “chat” : {
        “chat-uid-9283”: {
            “message-uid-a1b2” : {
                “message”: “Hey!! Testing chat!!”
                “send_by”: “did-1234”
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when you are showing the information about CHAT and/or PUBLICATION, you can use the value from the keys: posted_by and  send_by to get user’s informations.